# Can't trigger html-event from Google Apps Script sidebar

Tags: html, google-apps-script, onchange, sidebar, eventtrigger

I have a Google Apps Script in a Spreadsheet where a html-sidebar contains a select-tagg.

I can't get the onchange-event to trigger the setSheet-function.

HTML-code

```
<select onchange="google.script.run.setSheet(this.value)">
<? for (var i = 0; i < goodSheets.length; i++) { ?>
  <? var gs = goodSheets[i];?>
  <option value="<?= gs ?>" <? if(gs==sheetName){ ?> selected <? } ?> >
    <?= gs ?>
  </option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

GS-code

```
function setSheet(sheetName){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetName(sheetName));
}
```

Comment: Put a `Logger.log('it ran!' + sheetName)` statement as the first line of the `setSheet()` function, change the list box, then in the VIEW menu, look in the LOG.  What is there?   Also, use the f12 key to open the browsers console, and see if there are any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Sandy Good!
F12 showed that getSheetByName was misspelled. Was some delay but finally it worked with the line: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).activate();